# I want to group one columns based on a condition on another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table like this :

```
Column A | Column B
---------+---------
   1     |    A
   1     |    B
   2     |    A
   2     |    A
   2     |    C
   3     |    A
   3     |    A
   3     |    B
   3     |    B
```

I want to write a query that groups the values in such  a way that i get a table like this :

```
Column A | Column B
---------+---------
   1     |    A
   1     |    B
   2     |    A
   2     |    C
   3     |    A
   3     |    B
```

Comment: Please provide what conditions you are wanting to group on. The example table structures do not provide a clear picture of what the conditions are.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` removes duplicates from your query result.

```
select distinct * from mytable;
```

An alternative would be aggregation. You'd get a result row per a and b by grouping by them. You'd only use this however, when you want aggregates, e.g. the number of rows, a sum, an average, etc., because otherwise you can use `DISTINCT` as shown and should prefer it.

```
select a, b, count(*) from mytable group by a, b;
```

Comment: Then your query is different from mine. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` on both column.

```
select col1, col2 from test group by col1,col2;
```

See [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/627fd/1)

Comment: you are using `oracle` so you should retag the question with relevant tags. 

however the query should be ok with oracle also if you are writing column and table names properly.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: for oracle it is mandatory to use `group by` but for mysql it is not needed. also he don't need the `count(*)`.

Comment: What jarlh refers to is that you don't aggregate anything, so you should not use `GROUP BY`. Neither in Oracle nor in MySQL. You'd use `DISTINCT` if you only wanted to get rid of duplicate rows. Moreover the query is exactly the same in Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: I don't need to aggregate here. you can see the fiddle. it returns exact output what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes it does. I said so in my answer. One *could* use `GROUP BY`, only, one *doesn't* when no aggregation is needed. If you merely want distinct result rows, use `DISTINCT`.